# CBC solver Result - Linear relaxation infeasible

Tags: coin-or-cbc

I am trying to solve an LP problem with the CBC solver in Linux.

When I try t solve it, the model is determined linearly infeasible but a solution is found, so I don't understand why this is happening.

This is the solver output:

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.5 
Build Date: Oct 15 2020 

command line - cbc tt2.lp solve printing csv solu sol.txt (default strategy 1)
Presolve determined that the problem was infeasible with tolerance of 1e-08
Analysis indicates model infeasible or unbounded
Perturbing problem by 0.001% of 6368.0221 - largest nonzero change 9.6555471e-05 ( 8.8302642e-05%) - largest zero change 6.095558e-05
0  Obj 0 Primal inf 1303.3614 (30) Dual inf 6484.7494 (8)
0  Obj 0 Primal inf 1303.3614 (30) Dual inf 1.437715e+13 (28)
36  Obj -16980 Primal inf 105.38866 (21) Dual inf 7.2658581e+12 (14) w.o. free dual inf (13)
58  Obj -16046.434 Primal inf 0.28949488 (2)
Primal infeasible - objective value -16046.434
PrimalInfeasible objective -16046.43383 - 58 iterations time 0.002

Result - Linear relaxation infeasible

Enumerated nodes:           0
Total iterations:           0
Time (CPU seconds):         0.01
Time (Wallclock Seconds):   0.02

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to csv
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.03
```

I turned off preprocessing to see if it made any changes but it didn't.

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.5 
Build Date: Oct 15 2020 

command line - cbc tt2.lp preprocess off passp 0 solve printing csv solu sol.txt (default strategy 1)
Option for preprocess changed from sos to off
passPresolve was changed from 5 to 0
Perturbing problem by 0.001% of 6368.0221 - largest nonzero change 9.6555471e-05 ( 8.8302642e-05%) - largest zero change 6.095558e-05
0  Obj 0 Primal inf 1303.3614 (30) Dual inf 6484.7494 (8)
0  Obj 0 Primal inf 1303.3614 (30) Dual inf 1.437715e+13 (28)
36  Obj -16980 Primal inf 105.38866 (21) Dual inf 7.2658581e+12 (14) w.o. free dual inf (13)
58  Obj -16046.434 Primal inf 0.28949488 (2)
Primal infeasible - objective value -16046.434
PrimalInfeasible objective -16046.43383 - 58 iterations time 0.002

Result - Linear relaxation infeasible

Enumerated nodes:           0
Total iterations:           0
Time (CPU seconds):         0.00
Time (Wallclock Seconds):   0.02

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to csv
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.03
```

So the problem is that the Linear Relaxation of the LP problem is infeasible, but I don't know what this means or how to solve it.

This is the LP file in case it helps.

```
Minimize
    1.0 cv_1_1 - 1.0 w_1_1 + 2.0 cv_2_1 - 2.0 w_2_1 + 4.0 cv_1_2 - 4.0 w_1_2 + 8.0 cv_2_2 - 8.0 w_2_2 + 9.0 cv_1_3 - 9.0 w_1_3 + 18.0 cv_2_3 - 18.0 w_2_3 + 16.0 cv_1_4 - 16.0 w_1_4 + 32.0 cv_2_4 - 32.0 w_2_4 + 1 dmv_2_1 + 1 dmv_2_2

Subject To

    \Manipulated variables: initial value
    R0: mv_1_0 = 150
    R1: mv_2_0 = 150

    \States: initial value
    R2: x_1_0 = 0.03534155
    R3: x_2_0 = 0.07947994
    R4: x_3_0 = -0.00548606
    R5: x_4_0 = -0.28400902

    \Manipulated variables: change variables
    R6: dmv_1_1 - mv_1_1 + mv_1_0 = 0
    R7: dmv_1_2 - mv_1_2 + mv_1_1 = 0
    R8: dmv_1_3 - mv_1_3 + mv_1_2 = 0
    R9: dmv_1_4 - mv_1_4 + mv_1_3 = 0
    R10: dmv_2_1 - mv_2_1 + mv_2_0 = 0
    R11: dmv_2_2 - mv_2_2 + mv_2_1 = 0
    R12: dmv_2_3 - mv_2_3 + mv_2_2 = 0
    R13: dmv_2_4 - mv_2_4 + mv_2_3 = 0

    \Controlled variables: upper and lower bounds
    R14: cv_1_1 >= 45
    R15: cv_1_1 <= 65
    R16: cv_1_2 >= 45
    R17: cv_1_2 <= 65
    R18: cv_1_3 >= 45
    R19: cv_1_3 <= 65
    R20: cv_1_4 >= 45
    R21: cv_1_4 <= 65
    R22: cv_2_1 >= 5
    R23: cv_2_1 <= 11
    R24: cv_2_2 >= 5
    R25: cv_2_2 <= 11
    R26: cv_2_3 >= 5
    R27: cv_2_3 <= 11
    R28: cv_2_4 >= 5
    R29: cv_2_4 <= 11

    \Manipulated variables: ratio change allowed
    R30: dmv_1_1 <= 1
    R31: dmv_1_1 >= -1
    R32: dmv_1_2 <= 1
    R33: dmv_1_2 >= -1
    R34: dmv_1_3 <= 0.0
    R35: dmv_1_3 >= -0.0
    R36: dmv_1_4 <= 0.0
    R37: dmv_1_4 >= -0.0
    R38: dmv_2_1 <= 1
    R39: dmv_2_1 >= -1
    R40: dmv_2_2 <= 1
    R41: dmv_2_2 >= -1
    R42: dmv_2_3 <= 0.0
    R43: dmv_2_3 >= -0.0
    R44: dmv_2_4 <= 0.0
    R45: dmv_2_4 >= -0.0

    \Manipulated variables: upper and lower bounds
    R46: mv_1_1 >= 140
    R47: mv_1_1 <= 170
    R48: mv_1_2 >= 140
    R49: mv_1_2 <= 170
    R50: mv_1_3 >= 140
    R51: mv_1_3 <= 170
    R52: mv_1_4 >= 140
    R53: mv_1_4 <= 170
    R54: mv_2_1 >= 130
    R55: mv_2_1 <= 150
    R56: mv_2_2 >= 130
    R57: mv_2_2 <= 150
    R58: mv_2_3 >= 130
    R59: mv_2_3 <= 150
    R60: mv_2_4 >= 130
    R61: mv_2_4 <= 150

    \W: reference trajectories for controlled variables
    R62: w_1_1 = 10.0
    R63: w_1_2 = 40.0
    R64: w_1_3 = 90.0
    R65: w_1_4 = 160.0
    R66: w_2_1 = 20.0
    R67: w_2_2 = 80.0
    R68: w_2_3 = 180.0
    R69: w_2_4 = 320.0

    \Model
    \X(t+1) - Gx(t) - Hmv(t) = 0
    \cv(t) - Cx(t) = 0

    R70: x_1_2 - 1.001 x_1_1 + 0.0001777 x_2_1 + 0.02923 x_3_1 + 0.001065 x_4_1 - 5.049e-06 mv_1_1 + 8.92e-06 mv_2_1 = 0
    R71: x_2_2 - 0.001961 x_1_1 - 0.9536 x_2_1 - 0.009859 x_3_1 + 0.08002 x_4_1 - 9.27e-06 mv_1_1 + 0.0001443 mv_2_1 = 0
    R72: x_3_2 - 0.02647 x_1_1 + 0.006174 x_2_1 - 0.9386 x_3_1 + 0.07591 x_4_1 - 5.375e-05 mv_1_1 + 0.000216 mv_2_1 = 0
    R73: x_4_2 + 0.001008 x_1_1 - 0.2273 x_2_1 - 0.04935 x_3_1 - 0.6928 x_4_1 - 0.000377 mv_1_1 + 0.001151 mv_2_1 = 0
    R74: cv_1_1 - 1408.0 x_1_1 + 10.67 x_2_1 + 19.4 x_3_1 - 0.6612 x_4_1 = 0
    R75: cv_2_1 - 4.282 x_1_1 - 77.07 x_2_1 - 0.1379 x_3_1 + 2.884 x_4_1 = 0
    R76: x_1_3 - 1.001 x_1_2 + 0.0001777 x_2_2 + 0.02923 x_3_2 + 0.001065 x_4_2 - 5.049e-06 mv_1_2 + 8.92e-06 mv_2_2 = 0
    R77: x_2_3 - 0.001961 x_1_2 - 0.9536 x_2_2 - 0.009859 x_3_2 + 0.08002 x_4_2 - 9.27e-06 mv_1_2 + 0.0001443 mv_2_2 = 0
    R78: x_3_3 - 0.02647 x_1_2 + 0.006174 x_2_2 - 0.9386 x_3_2 + 0.07591 x_4_2 - 5.375e-05 mv_1_2 + 0.000216 mv_2_2 = 0
    R79: x_4_3 + 0.001008 x_1_2 - 0.2273 x_2_2 - 0.04935 x_3_2 - 0.6928 x_4_2 - 0.000377 mv_1_2 + 0.001151 mv_2_2 = 0
    R80: cv_1_2 - 1408.0 x_1_2 + 10.67 x_2_2 + 19.4 x_3_2 - 0.6612 x_4_2 = 0
    R81: cv_2_2 - 4.282 x_1_2 - 77.07 x_2_2 - 0.1379 x_3_2 + 2.884 x_4_2 = 0
    R82: x_1_4 - 1.001 x_1_3 + 0.0001777 x_2_3 + 0.02923 x_3_3 + 0.001065 x_4_3 - 5.049e-06 mv_1_3 + 8.92e-06 mv_2_3 = 0
    R83: x_2_4 - 0.001961 x_1_3 - 0.9536 x_2_3 - 0.009859 x_3_3 + 0.08002 x_4_3 - 9.27e-06 mv_1_3 + 0.0001443 mv_2_3 = 0
    R84: x_3_4 - 0.02647 x_1_3 + 0.006174 x_2_3 - 0.9386 x_3_3 + 0.07591 x_4_3 - 5.375e-05 mv_1_3 + 0.000216 mv_2_3 = 0
    R85: x_4_4 + 0.001008 x_1_3 - 0.2273 x_2_3 - 0.04935 x_3_3 - 0.6928 x_4_3 - 0.000377 mv_1_3 + 0.001151 mv_2_3 = 0
    R86: cv_1_3 - 1408.0 x_1_3 + 10.67 x_2_3 + 19.4 x_3_3 - 0.6612 x_4_3 = 0
    R87: cv_2_3 - 4.282 x_1_3 - 77.07 x_2_3 - 0.1379 x_3_3 + 2.884 x_4_3 = 0
    R88: x_1_5 - 1.001 x_1_4 + 0.0001777 x_2_4 + 0.02923 x_3_4 + 0.001065 x_4_4 - 5.049e-06 mv_1_4 + 8.92e-06 mv_2_4 = 0
    R89: x_2_5 - 0.001961 x_1_4 - 0.9536 x_2_4 - 0.009859 x_3_4 + 0.08002 x_4_4 - 9.27e-06 mv_1_4 + 0.0001443 mv_2_4 = 0
    R90: x_3_5 - 0.02647 x_1_4 + 0.006174 x_2_4 - 0.9386 x_3_4 + 0.07591 x_4_4 - 5.375e-05 mv_1_4 + 0.000216 mv_2_4 = 0
    R91: x_4_5 + 0.001008 x_1_4 - 0.2273 x_2_4 - 0.04935 x_3_4 - 0.6928 x_4_4 - 0.000377 mv_1_4 + 0.001151 mv_2_4 = 0
    R92: cv_1_4 - 1408.0 x_1_4 + 10.67 x_2_4 + 19.4 x_3_4 - 0.6612 x_4_4 = 0
    R93: cv_2_4 - 4.282 x_1_4 - 77.07 x_2_4 - 0.1379 x_3_4 + 2.884 x_4_4 = 0

Bounds
    \States: upper and lower bounds
    x_1_1 free
    x_1_2 free
    x_1_3 free
    x_1_4 free
    x_1_5 free
    x_2_1 free
    x_2_2 free
    x_2_3 free
    x_2_4 free
    x_2_5 free
    x_3_1 free
    x_3_2 free
    x_3_3 free
    x_3_4 free
    x_3_5 free
    x_4_1 free
    x_4_2 free
    x_4_3 free
    x_4_4 free
    x_4_5 free

 End
```

Comment: hi perhaps modify the objective function? might be of interest https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc/issues/286

Comment: From what I understand, "infeasible" means that there is no solution that satisfies all constraints. The solution that the solver provides is an infeasible solution, meaning the solution does not fulfill all of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I somewhat despise those txt-based serialization-formats and this means, that i'm not an expert because i don't use them often.

**My guess:**

- Variables are by default non-negative

  - Lower-bound: 0.0
  - Upper-bound: positive infinity

**This is a very common design-decision in various solvers** and in regards to the LP-file i guess it might be true too (?).

(A quick glimpse through Gurobi, CPLEX, FICO commercial solvers make me think all of those apply this logic -> CoinOR Clp/Cbc probably does the same)

**A:**
Let's take some other solver and run your file:

- infeasible
- says: `R4: x_3_0 = -0.00548606` is not okay (there might be other source of infeasibility)

**B:**
Your lp-file contains:

```
Bounds
    \States: upper and lower bounds
    x_1_1 free
    ...
```

- Free variables are [-infinity, +infinity] variables -> not non-negative
- Seeing those explicitly here somewhat indicates a potential default as we guess above

**C:**

- `x_3_0` does not appear in free-vars
- `x_3_0` is probably in `[0, +infinity)`

  - Obviously incompatible with `R4: x_3_0 = -0.00548606`

    - And it's such a simple deduction, that presolving recognizes that

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error info, and I solve this problem just by increasing the var bound. For example, (0, 1000) -> (0, 10000).